# Bridge Networking On Alpine Linux

Tags: networking, alpine-linux

I am trying to set up three interfaces on an ExpressoBin while running Alpine as my OS. I want ports lan0 and lan1 to be bridged and have the bridge port attempt to collect an IP via DHCP, then I want the third leftover port to collect an IP via DHCP also. I seem to be running into a good bit of trouble and I think I may be fighting the networking service at times. Below is a set of networking setups I have tried to run with no success so far.
What should work: (Should be simple right?)

```
auto lan0
iface lan0 inet manual

auto lan1
iface lan1 inet manual

auto wan
iface wan inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports lan1 lan0
Errors:
* Starting networking ... *   lan0 ... [ ok ]
 *   lan1 ... [ ok ]
 *   wan ...ip: ioctl 0x8914 failed: Network is down
 [ !! ]
 *   br0 ...ip: ioctl 0x8914 failed: Network is down
ip: ioctl 0x8914 failed: Network is down
sending commands to master dhcpcd process
```

Not sure why  br0 "Network is down" when its not a true physical interface I would expect it to be up if it is being built and having interfaces assigned to it?
Whats strange is I get an ip on lan1 but no network access:
ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: bond0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP400> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether ee:5d:d4:7a:8e:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 532
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:06:e0:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.75.204/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2d7e:4f3:18e4:6779/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: wan@eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:06:e0:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: lan0@eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state LOWERLAYERDOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:06:e0:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: lan1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:06:e0:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.40.7/28 brd 10.0.40.15 scope global dynamic lan1
       valid_lft 85768sec preferred_lft 74968sec
    inet6 fe80::2d7e:4f3:18e4:6779/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:06:e0:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::f2ad:4eff:fe06:e018/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route list:

```
default via 10.0.40.1 dev lan1  src 10.0.40.7  metric 207 
10.0.40.0/28 dev lan1 scope link  src 10.0.40.7  metric 207 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link  src 169.254.75.204  metric 204
```

but ping does not work, even though I have an Ip and a route that looks to be correct to me.

Using an older interfaces format:
This should not be needed give my ALpine build version is higher than the version stated in this link [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Bridge),

```
auto wan                      
iface wan inet dhcp           
                                
auto br0                                                             
iface br0 inet static                                               
        pre-up brctl addbr br0                                       
        pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-arptables
        pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
        post-down brctl delbr br0          
                                           
auto lan0                                  
iface lan0 inet manual                     
        up ip link set lan0 up             
        up brctl addif br0 lan0            
        down brctl delif br0 lan0 || true  
        down ip link set lan0 down         
                                           
auto lan1                                  
iface lan1 inet manual                     
        up ip link set lan1 up             
        up brctl addif br0 lan1                                      
        down brctl delif br0 lan1 || true                                                        
        down ip link set lan1 down
```

Errors:

```
 * Starting networking ... *   wan ...ip: ioctl 0x8914 failed: Network is down
 [ !! ]
 *   br0 ...ifup: don't have all variables for br0/inet
 [ !! ]
 *   lan0 ...ip: ioctl 0x8914 failed: Network is down
 [ !! ]
 *   lan1 ...ip: ioctl 0x8914 failed: Network is down
*snip*
 * Starting networking ... *   wan ...sending commands to master dhcpcd process
 [ ok ]
 *   br0 ...ifup: don't have all variables for br0/inet
 [ !! ]
 *   lan0 ...brctl: bridge br0: No such device
 [ !! ]
 *   lan1 ...brctl: bridge br0: No such device
 [ !! ]
```

End result:
I get an Ip address on lan1 not br0.

```
7: lan1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:ad:4e:06:e0:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.40.7/28 brd 10.0.40.15 scope global dynamic lan1
       valid_lft 85737sec preferred_lft 74937sec
```

Can anyone direct me to what I am screwing up here? I even attempted switching to networkmanager service and configuring that via nmtui and I didn't get any further. Once again lan1 got an IP via DHCP but failed to actually properly setup the networking as I intended.

Comment: lan0/lan1 are real, physical interfaces?

Comment: `ip -details link` or `ip -details addr` would allow to check what are these interfaces. Eg: they could be presented as vlan interfaces. They are DSA/switchdev ports with eth0 the data plane interface, eth0 appears to have a dual role. (some ref: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=f0c05e876212afdf2b7e39da99d5c928f0dbbd56 ). So there is probably interaction between the driver, maybe internal vlans (if I guessed correctly) and the bridge